# Form POST not working in web-based Task module

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

In my Web-based Task Module I display a button for the user to click if they accept certain conditions. The page has a form element with several hidden inputs to send a POST request to open a web page in a new browser window. When the user clicks the button on the page, we call a javascript function that calls the submit() method on the form and when the submit() completes calls microsoftTeams.tasks.submitTask() with the success results to close the Task Module.

```
<html>
<body>
  <script>
    microsoftTeams.initialize();
    function buttonClick() {
      // have the form submit to open the external document
      document.getElementById("openNewDocument").submit();
      // tell the bot the user didn't cancel
      microsoftTeams.tasks.submitTask(
        {"command":"openDocument", "success":"true"},
        [ {my App ID} ]
      );
    }
  </script>
  <form
    id="openNewDocument"
    method="post"
    action={url to document server}
    target="_blank"
  >
    <input hidden="true" name="docContext" value={encryptedContext} />
    <input hidden="true" name="activityId" value={activityId} />
    <input hidden="true" name="participantId" value={participantId} />
    <input hidden="true" name="tid" value={tid} />
  </form>
  <button label="open document" onClick=buttonClick()>
    Open document
  </button>
</body>
</html>
```

In the web browser the code works just fine. But in the Desktop Teams app (MacOS) the POST request is sent as a GET and the hidden inputs are ignored.

Is there a secret to getting the Form data send as a POST?

Comment: Please follow this [sample code](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/main/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/54.teams-task-module/Pages/CustomForm.cshtml) and let me know if you still persist the issue,

Comment: @Mamatha-MSFT your example sends the contents of the form as the response to the task. My intent is to open a new browser window sending values printed in the html page as values to authenticate opening a secure page.
I'll update my question with a code snippet.

Comment: I am able to repro the issue. I Will check this internally and get back to you.

Answer (score 0):

Form POST will not work in Task module. You need to call chaining in task module. Please go through this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/messaging-extensions/how-to/action-commands/respond-to-task-module-submit?tabs=dotnet%2Cdotnet-1#respond-with-another-task-module).

Comment: I don't see how task chaining can solve the problem. Task modules that host a web app are loaded with a GET. And the openUrl action also only issues a GET.

Comment: @NormanStratton - Alternatively you can use Ajax post method to post data.